# I loved her more that I've done any of my exes. - does this sentence make sense?

Tags: sentence-construction

I loved her more that I've done any of my exes.

this is the first sentence that I've come up with. but the girl that broke up with me is now another ex. So is the following sentence better?

> 1. I loved her more that I've done any of the other exes of mine.
> 2. I loved her more that I've done any of my other exes
> 3. I loved her more that I've done any of my the other exes.
> 4. I loved her more that I've done any of the other exes.

I think #4 sounds best. and #3 doesn't make sense because 'my' is already implying a definite so we don't need to use definite article 'the'. and I don't know if #1 and #2 sounds natural. can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you mean *than* instead of *that*.

And I don't think I would use *done* here to refer to *loved*.  It's confusing to me (though I think this usage may perhaps be more common among British speakers; I'm American).  Worse, it sets up an ambiguity with the slang sense of *do* meaning *have sex with*.

I would simply write

> I loved her more than I've loved any of my other exes.

Or if you want to avoid repeating the verb *loved*

> I loved her more than any of my other exes.

You are right that the use of *other* implies that the woman who is the object of *loved* is also an ex.

You are right that #3 is incorrect; the definite article *the* should not be used together with *my*.

As to #4, if you write

> I loved her more than I loved any of the other exes.

then it is correct but sounds impersonal; the others are exes (of somebody), but it's not so clear that they are *your* exes.  You could clarify this with

> I loved her more than I loved any of the other exes of mine.

Then it is clear, but I think it is becoming too wordy.